# Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: android, input, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg lib in my library.For that purpose,i have successfully compiled it.The input video is otherwise running fine,but when i try to execute any command,i am getting this message:

```
Invalid data found when processing input.
```

I don't know whats the reason behind it.This is the code:

```
 public class Videokit extends Activity {
        String FilePath;
        String OutPut;
        Context mycontext;
        Videokit vk ;
        static 
        {
            System.loadLibrary("videokit");
        }

        public native void run(String[] args);

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            FilePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/output.3gp";
            try {
                ffmpegrun();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String ffmpegrun() throws IOException
        {
            boolean success=false;
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/image-%3d.jpeg");
            File file = new File(FilePath);
            System.out.println("filepath exists at:"+file.getAbsolutePath());
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
    //              Toast.makeText(mycontext,"outfile.mp4 exists at"+folder.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 OutPut = folder.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            System.out.println("outfile.flv exists at:"+folder.getAbsolutePath());
            run(new String[]{
                    "ffmpeg",
                    "-i",
                    FilePath,
                    "-r 1", 
                     "-f",
                     "image2",
                     "image-%3d.jpeg"
            }); 
            return OutPut;
        }
    }
```

This is the log :

```
10-07 17:00:03.707: D/dalvikvm(8760): Trying to load lib /data/data/uk.co.halfninja.videokit/lib/libvideokit.so 0x44e8c958
10-07 17:00:03.837: D/dalvikvm(8760): Added shared lib /data/data/uk.co.halfninja.videokit/lib/libvideokit.so 0x44e8c958
10-07 17:00:03.837: I/Videokit(8760): Loading native library compiled at 13:52:27 Oct  7 2012
10-07 17:00:03.917: I/System.out(8760): filepath exists at:/sdcard/output.3gp
10-07 17:00:03.917: I/System.out(8760): outfile.flv exists at:/sdcard/image-%3d.jpeg
10-07 17:00:03.917: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.917: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/dalvikvm(8760): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libexif.so' for 'run' (wrong CL)
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): run() called
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): run passing off to main()
10-07 17:00:03.928: D/Videokit(8760): main(): registering all modules
10-07 17:00:03.938: D/Videokit(8760): main(): registered everything
10-07 17:00:03.938: D/Videokit(8760): main(): initting opts
10-07 17:00:03.968: D/Videokit(8760): main(): initted opts.
10-07 17:00:03.968: E/Videokit(8760): ffmpeg version N-30996-gf925b24, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
10-07 17:00:03.979: E/Videokit(8760):   built on Oct  7 2012 13:52:32 with gcc 4.4.3
10-07 17:00:03.979: E/Videokit(8760):   configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm5te --enable-armv5te --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --prefix=../output --disable-neon --enable-version3 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --ld=arm-linux-androideabi-ld --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated' --disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccels --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --disable-demuxer=v4l --disable-demuxer=v4l2 --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2 --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -Ivideokit' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264
10-07 17:00:03.987: D/Videokit(8760): main(): parsing options
10-07 17:00:03.987: D/Videokit(8760): parse_options has 7 options to parse
10-07 17:00:04.050: E/Videokit(8760): /sdcard/output.3gp: Invalid data found when processing input
10-07 17:00:04.050: E/Videokit(8760): ffmpeg_exit(1) called!
```

Please help me.I am clueless about this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @subbareddy-polamreddy Please do not edit out white space from a question like this.

Comment: '/sdcard/output.3gp' looks like that is not valid data. You really need to help us help you. Provide more information about where it is breaking, how you know it is breaking, what the correct behaviour should be, what attempts have you made to fix etc.

Comment: Sir you can clearly see from the log cat itself that i am passing the arguments to ffmpeg via jni.When it comes to input the data e.g mp4 file,it is showing the message in the log cat that the input data is invalid.I have tried many input formats e.g flv,3gp and many other playable videos.But i am getting the same message in return every time.

Comment: The correct behaviour should be to take the input,process it and to produce the relevant output.But it is not taking the input even.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compiled FFmpeg to be able to handle flv or 3gp... files?
I see that mp4 is in the compilation but flv and 3gp are not...